# Master-Slave JK Flip Flop toggles on both edges

Tags: transistors

I'm trying to make a MS JK Flip Flop with Preset and Clear using only transistors(BC547B) and resistors in LTSpiceXVII. I made four 3-input NAND gates for the master flip flop and four 2-input ones for the slave. When I ran the simulation and measured the voltages at the outputs they were not what I expected. Q toggles on both edges of the clock pulse and Q` just varies slightly. I'm not very well versed in electronics so could anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong.

[image: Logic Diagram]Logic Diagram
[image: Schematic]Schematic
[image: Clock pulse]Clock Pulse
[image: Voltage at Q]Voltage at Q
[image: Voltage at Q`]Voltage at Q'

Comment: Which node is V(n20)?

Comment: @devnull The node at the right of the voltage source named PULSE I also edited my post to add a logic diagram and Image descriptions